# Surfaces in cube must intersect in curve

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

It's a consequence of the Jordan Curve Theorem that two curves linking different pairs of opposite sides of a square must intersect. I've been wondering about generalisations of this, how manifolds with boundaries intersecting, dividing themselves into pieces in particular patterns must intersect. A general reference on this topic would be great, but a specific question I have is the following. In the unit cube we have two faces perpendicular to each standard basis vector in the space containing it. For basis vector $e_k$, we will denote the union of these faces $F_k$. Let $s,t:[0,1]^2\to[0,1]^3$ be continuous, with $s$ mapping the boundary of the square to $F_0\cup F_1$ and $t$ mapping it to $F_0\cup F_2$ such that $[\partial s]$ is not nullhomotopic in $F_0\cup F_1$ and $[\partial t]$ is not nullhomotopic in $F_0\cup F_2$. Must the intersection of $s$ and $t$ contain a curve $c:[0,1]\to[0,1]^3$ with endpoints on opposite faces of $F_0$? Furthermore, must this curve $c$ be a composition of $s$ with a curve $c_s:[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ and the same for $t$?

Comment: You can easily construct two curves $s' : [0..1] \to F_0 \cup F_1$ and $t' : [0..1] \to F_0 \cup F_2$ such that $\operatorname{im}(s') \cap \operatorname{im}(t') = \emptyset$ and $\operatorname{im}(s'), \operatorname{im}(t')$ touches all four respective possible faces. After that you can take $s(x,y) = s'(x), t(x,y)=t'(x), s: [0..1]^2 \to F_0 \cup F_1, t: [0..1]^2 \to F_0 \cup F_2$ and this will be a counterexample. What you really want to say is that $[\partial s] \neq 0$ in $H_1(F_0 \cup F_1, \mathbb Z)$ and $[\partial t] \neq 0$ in $H_1(F_0 \cup F_2, \mathbb Z)$.